# How to use [(ngModel)] on div's contenteditable in angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, contenteditable

I am trying to use ngModel to two way bind div's contenteditable input content as follows:

```
<div id="replyiput" class="btn-input"  [(ngModel)]="replyContent"  contenteditable="true" data-text="type..." style="outline: none;"    ></div>
```

but it is not working and an error occurs:

```
EXCEPTION: No value accessor for '' in [ddd in PostContent@64:141]
app.bundle.js:33898 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

`NgModel` expects the bound element to have a `value` property, which `div`s don't have.  That's why you get the `No value accessor` error.

You can set up your own equivalent property and event databinding using the `textContent` property (instead of `value`) and the `input` event:

```js
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `{{ title }}
        <div contenteditable="true" [textContent]="model" (input)="model = $event.target.textContent"></div>
        <p>{{ model }}</p>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = "Angular 2 RC.4";
    model = "some text";
    constructor() {
        console.clear();
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KCeKTPu8dJI0O1nVMPfb?p=preview)</kbd>

I don't know if the `input` event is supported on all browsers for `contenteditable`.  You could always bind to some keyboard event instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not a two way binding. When the user type something in the input,  the "model" var will not change.

Comment: @KimWong, the `model` var is definitely changing in the Plunker I provided.  That's why I put `{{model}}` in the view/template, so that we can see it change when we edit the div.

Comment: Thx! This helps. For some reason angular2rc1 does not like textContent, using innerText instead works fine.

Comment: Big help thank you! Any way to easily support multiline and resist the text from being generated at the beginning of the line i.e. backwards?

Comment: @ZachBotterman, if I add `styles: ['div { white-space: pre}' ]` to the component metadata it sort of works.  I have to type shift-enter for the newline to not be replaced.  Tested on Chrome only.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thanks for the reply. Will check asap

Comment: I ran into the same issue, got it working in a slightly different way answered below.

Comment: Regardless of the event used to trigger model=$event.target.textContent, this currently doesn't work properly on Firefox and Edge. The cursor is always set at index 0 when typing. You should be aware of this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a little more complex use case. I also have an attribute level directive in the same div and I need to have 2 way binding for "model". So that my directive will get the updated model and if I change the model from directive, it's reflected in UI. How do I do that?

Comment: guys, anyone know how to sort out so the cursor index to not be set at 0 all the time?

Comment: This doesnot work in IE. Just open the plunker in IE.

Comment: currently this is only useful for typing backwards

Comment: @MarkRajcok Great solution. But your plunker do not work fine in firefox. It types backward in firefox. I have added post for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206076/contenteditable-div-is-not-working-properly-with-angular-two-way-binding-in-fire
Need your help.

Answer (score 17):

Working Plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/j9fDFc, but relevant code below.

---

Binding to and manually updating `textContent` wasn't working for me, it doesn't handle line breaks (in Chrome, typing after a line break jumps cursor back to the beginning) but I was able to get it work using a contenteditable model directive from https://www.namekdev.net/2016/01/two-way-binding-to-contenteditable-element-in-angular-2/.

I tweaked it to handle multi-line plain text (with `\n`s, not `<br>`s) by using `white-space: pre-wrap`, and updated it to use `keyup` instead of `blur`. Note that some solutions to this problem use the `input` event which isn't supported on IE or Edge on `contenteditable` elements yet.

Here's the code:

**Directive:**

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[contenteditableModel]',
  host: {
    '(keyup)': 'onKeyup()'
  }
})
export class ContenteditableModel {
  @Input('contenteditableModel') model: string;
  @Output('contenteditableModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();

  /**
   * By updating this property on keyup, and checking against it during
   * ngOnChanges, we can rule out change events fired by our own onKeyup.
   * Ideally we would not have to check against the whole string on every
   * change, could possibly store a flag during onKeyup and test against that
   * flag in ngOnChanges, but implementation details of Angular change detection
   * cycle might make this not work in some edge cases?
   */
  private lastViewModel: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['model'] && changes['model'].currentValue !== this.lastViewModel) {
      this.lastViewModel = this.model;
      this.refreshView();
    }
  }

  /** This should probably be debounced. */
  onKeyup() {
    var value = this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText;
    this.lastViewModel = value;
    this.update.emit(value);
  }

  private refreshView() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText = this.model
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {ContenteditableModel} from './contenteditable-model'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  directives: [ContenteditableModel],
  styles: [
    `div {
      white-space: pre-wrap;

      /* just for looks: */
      border: 1px solid coral;
      width: 200px;
      min-height: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }`
  ],
  template: `
    <b>contenteditable:</b>
    <div contenteditable="true" [(contenteditableModel)]="text"></div>

    <b>Output:</b>
    <div>{{text}}</div>

    <b>Input:</b><br>
    <button (click)="text='Success!'">Set model to "Success!"</button>
  `
})
export class App {
  text: string;

  constructor() {
    this.text = "This works\nwith multiple\n\nlines"
  }
}
```

Only tested in Chrome and FF on Linux so far.

Comment: Tested on Firefox with Windows as well, under Ionic 2, and your code works there as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

**Updated answer (2017-10-09)**:

Now I have [ng-contenteditable](https://github.com/KostyaTretyak/ng-contenteditable) module. Its compatibility with Angular forms.

**Old answer (2017-05-11)**:
In my case, I can simple to do:

```html
<div
  contenteditable="true"
  (input)="post.postTitle = $event.target.innerText"
  >{{ postTitle }}</div>
```

Where `post` - it's object with property `postTitle`.

First time, after `ngOnInit()` and get `post` from backend, I set `this.postTitle = post.postTitle` in my component.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you allow the user to edit their response after they have moved on to another screen (preset values).

Answer (score 13):

Here's [another version](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lfe615?p=preview), based on @tobek's answer, which also supports html and pasting:

```ts
import {
  Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges, OnChanges,
  HostListener, Sanitizer, SecurityContext
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[contenteditableModel]'
})
export class ContenteditableDirective implements OnChanges {
  /** Model */
  @Input() contenteditableModel: string;
  @Output() contenteditableModelChange?= new EventEmitter();
  /** Allow (sanitized) html */
  @Input() contenteditableHtml?: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private sanitizer: Sanitizer
  ) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['contenteditableModel']) {
      // On init: if contenteditableModel is empty, read from DOM in case the element has content
      if (changes['contenteditableModel'].isFirstChange() && !this.contenteditableModel) {
        this.onInput(true);
      }
      this.refreshView();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('input') // input event would be sufficient, but isn't supported by IE
  @HostListener('blur')  // additional fallback
  @HostListener('keyup') onInput(trim = false) {
    let value = this.elRef.nativeElement[this.getProperty()];
    if (trim) {
      value = value.replace(/^[\n\s]+/, '');
      value = value.replace(/[\n\s]+$/, '');
    }
    this.contenteditableModelChange.emit(value);
  }

  @HostListener('paste') onPaste() {
    this.onInput();
    if (!this.contenteditableHtml) {
      // For text-only contenteditable, remove pasted HTML.
      // 1 tick wait is required for DOM update
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML !== this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText) {
          this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.elRef.nativeElement.innerText;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  private refreshView() {
    const newContent = this.sanitize(this.contenteditableModel);
    // Only refresh if content changed to avoid cursor loss
    // (as ngOnChanges can be triggered an additional time by onInput())
    if (newContent !== this.elRef.nativeElement[this.getProperty()]) {
      this.elRef.nativeElement[this.getProperty()] = newContent;
    }
  }

  private getProperty(): string {
    return this.contenteditableHtml ? 'innerHTML' : 'innerText';
  }

  private sanitize(content: string): string {
    return this.contenteditableHtml ? this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, content) : content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but to avoid **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError** please use asynchronous `EventEmitter` in output `@Output() contenteditableModelChange?= new EventEmitter(true);` [reference](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) to article. Maybe you can update your code.

Answer (score 7):

I've fiddled around with this solutions and will use the following solution in my project now:

```
<div #topicTitle contenteditable="true" [textContent]="model" (input)="model=topicTitle.innerText"></div>
```

I prefer using the template reference variable to the "$event" stuff.

Related  link:
https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable

Comment: I used this solution on an editable TD as well. {{model}} as suggested by some other solutions gave me issues while typing. It would dynamically update the text and I would get some garbled gibberish, with this solution that didn't happen

Comment: I like the solution, but it also types backwards in firefox.

Answer (score 3):

In **contenteditable**, I've achieved the **two way binding** with help of the **blur** event and **innerHTML** attribute.

in .html:

```
<div placeholder="Write your message.."(blur)="getContent($event.target.innerHTML)" contenteditable [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

In .ts:

```
getContent(innerText){
  this.content = innerText;
}
```

Comment: This works fine when you use the innerHTML of $event.target in your save method (like I usually do). Here it is consistent:  innerHTML both ways.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was enough to use javascript, without the ts object. 
HTML:

```
 <div
        id="custom-input"
        placeholder="Schreiben..."
</div>
```

TS:

- to get the input value: `document.getElementById("custom-input").innerHTML`
- to set the input value: `document.getElementById("custom-input").innerHTML = "myValue"`

And everything works perfectly. I was forced to use a div instead of ionic ion-textarea because I had problems with autosize. With ion-textarea I was able to make autosize only with js. Now I make autosize with CSS, which I think is better.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution if what you are binding to is a string, no events necessary. Just put a text box input inside the table cell and bind to that. Then format your text box to transparent

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of tableList">
    <td>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="x.value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </td>
</tr>
```