# How can i change div contenteditable = "false" to "true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am playing around with angular2. I want to change the value of a div-
Need to change all **contenteditable="false"** to **contenteditable="true"** which are there on my HTML page.

> Please note sometimes the contenteditable="false" will be added to a DIV tag and sometimes to P, h1 tag or some other.

The html looks as following:

```
<button (click)="selectDiv()">select div</button>
<section>
      <div class="content">
        <h1 contenteditable="false" >Resize your browser and see how they adapt.</h1>
        <h1 contenteditable="false" >text2.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="content" contenteditable="false">
        <p>Content 2.</p>
        <h1>text2.</h1>
      </div>
</section>
```

Please guide me what should i write in `explore.ts` so that when i click the button, `selectDiv()` is called and the function is executed and all the **contenteditable="false"** becomes **"true"**

> Please note there can be any number of contenteditable="false" in my code.

```
selectDiv(){
//what should i write here
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023701/angular-2-contenteditable

Comment: Can't you just write the attribute as `[contentEditable]="contentEditable"` and in your controller have that variable and just change it to `true` when you click the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an Angular way of doing it:

HTML

```
<button (click)="selectDiv()">select div</button>
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <h1 [contentEditable]="contentEditable">Resize your browser and see how they adapt.</h1>
    <h1 [contentEditable]="contentEditable">text2.</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content" [contentEditable]="contentEditable">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
    <h1>text2.</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

TypeScript Controller

```
...
private contentEditable: boolean = false;
...
selectDiv(): void {
    this.contentEditable = true;
}
...
```

Comment: what is the difference between `selectDiv(){}` and `selectDiv(): void{}` , it worked perfectly fine by the way..

Comment: Well, the only difference is that TypeScript knows that this method should not return anything. Otherwise it does not matter.

Comment: thanks i am accepting your answer, please if my question is nicely formatted, do accept it

Comment: Thanks @Arg0n. Everyone please ensure its [contentEditable] and not [contenteditable] on the html markup. You could spend the whole day looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the attribute and use `attr` property to update it's value.

Here all `h1` will be selected which have the `contenteditable` attribute

```js
function selectDiv() {
  $("h1[contenteditable='false']").attr('contenteditable', true)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="selectDiv()">
  select div</button>
<section>

  <div class="content">
    <h1 contenteditable="false">Resize your browser and see how they adapt.</h1>
    <h1 contenteditable="false">text2.</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content" contenteditable="false">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
    <h1>text2.</h1>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Remove `h1` from the selector, he wants all elements with the attribute.

Comment: @user2828442 you have not added jquery