# change event is not working on span in angular 4

Tags: angular, onchange

Angular 4 change event is working fine with input type text which is as below

```
<input type="text" (change)="updateData($event)"/>
```

but when we write code as below then It does't work.

```
<span id="fname" (change)="updateData($event)"></span>
```

Can anyone give me litter insight for this behavior and If possible then best way to achieve the same.

Comment: How do you expect that a non-interactive element is firing a `change` Event? A change event is only fired if the user's input changes. For example typing something in an input element.

Comment: I am making contenteditable="true" for span.

Comment: What prevents you from just using an input ? You're trying to force some functionallity on a poor little `span` element, which isn't there for such a strong task.

Comment: UI looks is design in such a way that we can't use input box.

Comment: I would doubt that you can't style an input in a way that only a span could be styled. Also `contenteditable` will raise a huge chunk of problems in numerous browsers. But if you want to use it try listening for the `input` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). Also be aware that IE doesn't know about it.

Comment: for angular2 contenteditable, this might be what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023701/angular-2-contenteditable

Comment: @cyrix, there's nothing wrong with using `contenteditable` elements. Form element `input` is not a replacement for them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `contenteditable` you need to use `input` event. [Here is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) what the docs say:

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an
>   , , or  element is changed... Additionally, it fires **on contenteditable editors when
>   its contents are changed.** In this case, the event target is the
>   editing host element...

`input` however is triggered on each change, while `change` is triggered on `focusout`, so you need to combine those.

```
class Component {
  tmp = ''l

  updateTmpData(e) {
    this.tmp = e.target.textContent;
  }

  updateData() {
     // use this.tmp
  }
}

... 
<span id="fname" (input)="updateTmpData(e)" (focusout)="updateData()"></span>
```

Comment: we have used some what same solution as you have suggested by comparing old and new values. Just wondering If there is better way around.  <span id="fname (click)="savePreviousValue($event)" (focusout)="updateData($event)"></span>

Comment: why are listening to the click event?

Comment: We could use focusin event as well and don't want to use input event because I don't want to send data on every character input.