# angular 2 input with image support

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to create a chat app with angular 2 and I need to show Emojis in the input field, but html doesn't support image in input field.
also I tried this way, but not worked:

```
<div contenteditable="true"
     [innerHtml]="msgText"
     class="form-control"
     (keyup)="enable_disable_sendBtn()"
     (keypress)="handle_enter_key($event)"
     #messageBox
     (input)="msgText = $event.target.innerText">
</div>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023701/angular-2-contenteditable/40183067#40183067) but not I've got errors from `tslint` and says: `use @HostListener Or @HostBinding instead of host`.
Can anyone help me to show emjis in the text input?

Comment: "but not worked" is not enough information. What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Any error messages?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use https://www.emojione.com/ or similar

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I expect to show images and it shows but the problem is when I try to write `amir` it writes `rima` so the problem is whenever a key is pressed (or keyup or keydown, I don't know what the problem is)  the caret goes to the first of input

Comment: This behavior doesn't look related to the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find a solution. the solution is one way binding, cause the user writes something in the `contenteditable` and I just need to get the `innerHTML` when I want e.g.: when to send the content.
also when I want to add an Image to the content, simply I add to the `contenteditable` and when I need to send (or something like) I get the `innerHTML` .

```
<div contenteditable="true"
   class="form-control"
   id="messageBox"
   #messageBox
   (keydown.enter)="handle_enter_key($event)"
   (input)="handleMessageBoxInput($event)">
</div>
```