# (ngModelChange) is not working with div in Angular 2

Tags: angular

My app.component.ts has below code

```
  public sendData(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

app.component.html has below code

```
 <div type="text" contenteditable="true" (ngModelChange)="sendData($event)" [innerHTML]="childSampleData" (input)="childSampleData=$event.target.innerHTML"
    style="background-color : pink">
```

sendData($event) is not working with  tag. ngModelChange() is not working with div tag.
Whereas, if I use below code (with input tag, also it works with textArea) sendData($event) is working fine.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ childSampleData }}" [(ngModel)]='childSampleData' (ngModelChange)="sendData($event)">
```

Can anyone suggest how to use ngModelChange() with div or there any other solution for achieving the same?

Comment: ngModelChange is used to watch the ngModel Directive fields not for Div change, for detecting Div change create a Custom directive

Answer (score 1):

ngModelChange fires when the model changes. You cannot use this event without ngModel directive.

Answer (score 1):

By default div are not supported by ngModel. But I'm assuming that you have some requirement (eg. to have same editable and non-editable view) for not using input instead of content editable div. Still, if you want to use div.
 See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378087/how-to-use-ngmodel-on-divs-contenteditable-in-angular2)