# Bind edited JSON in <pre> tag to the variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I display JSON in pre tag using json pipe. Unfortunately when I edit JSON I don't see changes in value variable so how can I bind these values?

```
<pre contenteditable="true">{{value | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: That binding is one way. You need to use events.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Could you provide me an example?

Comment: How you are editing the JSON?

Comment: Maybe this can help you a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378087/how-to-use-ngmodel-on-divs-contenteditable-in-angular2

Answer (score 1):

MAybe have you tried something like:

```
<input type="text" col="5" [(NgModel)]="value" />

<pre contenteditable="true">{{value | json}}</pre>
```

So put your json in a text area with a bind on your value?

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

I used `<textarea>` instead of `<pre>` and it solved my problem :)