# How to use "innerHTML "on the" textarea " component"?

Tags: angular

How to use "innerHTML" in the "textarea" component?
I do that but nothing works.

```
<textarea [innerHTML]="notebook.description"
    class="form-control" name="description" 
    style="height:320px"  [(ngModel)]='notebook.description' disabled>
</textarea>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `innerHTML` if you're setting `ngModel`

Comment: As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4705848/1009922), you cannot render HTML inside a `textarea` element.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35378087/1009922) for possible solutions with a `contenteditable` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

kind of workaround

in html

`<textarea [innerHTML]="getInnerHTML(name)" cols="" rows=""></textarea>`

and in .ts file

`getInnerHTML(val){
    return val.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');
  }`

refer the same on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnwgad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

---

//ignore below one

try using

`<textarea [innerHtml]="note.description"></textarea>`

or

`<textarea [(ngModel)]="note.description"></textarea>`

Comment: But there tags remain if remove "innerHtml"

Comment: i didn't get what you mean @user10149472

Comment: The text is displayed along with the tags in the "textarea" component

Comment: which approach you have used  [innerHtml] or [(ngModel)]

Comment: I used [innerHtml]

Comment: @user10149472    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnwgad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html   please look into it, i have tried with both ngModel and innerHtml and it works

Comment: @ravi - I think he has HTML tags in his bound string. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qbxi4).

Comment: @ConnorsFan you  are right ,if  you add tags in the value , tags are going to appear in the textarea

Comment: @user10149472 my bad i didn't get the problem, that issue was of tag containing in the string , just tried bit of workaround https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnwgad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html look into it might help