# How to edit HTML document with tags in textarea without displaying the tags?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

This is something I'm struggling a bit. I have this textarea which can display text with HTML tags. I'm using `Angular 10` and `angular-material/@latest`.

Here's the textarea that displays the HTML document.

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="editStatement">
                            <textarea matInput [innerHTML]="statement.statement_description_html"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

The form looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to not display the HTML tags but interpret it and show texts only in the textarea. Is that possible? Some in other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695041/how-to-use-innerhtml-on-the-textarea-component) suggests to do

```
<textarea [innerHTML]="getInnerHTML(name)" cols="" rows=""></textarea>

and in .ts file

getInnerHTML(val){
    return val.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');
  }
```

The problem with this approach is that it removes all the tags. I want to retain the tags but provide a way to edit the text - somewhat like some of the CMS systems like Wordpress, Wix etc.

Can I do this using Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a "WYSIWYG" HTML Editor (like [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/#)) that you can embed into your page.

Comment: I followed the direction and got to the point where I could make the WYSIWYG editor show up. How do I fill the editor with the data from the model? I couldn't  get it to work. Any pointers?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. It was quite easy, actually. I only needed to add `[(ngModel)]`. Thanks for suggesting this great tool.