# Angular 6: How to detect table data change in Angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular-changedetection

I am generating a very simple table by binding a table to an array. And I use the **contenteditable="true"** so I can edit each cell data on the client side. Here is my code:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of keys">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>

    <td contenteditable="true">
      {{ item.Value }}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" (click)="printContent()" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I detect the text changes on the cell that has ***contenteditable*** set to ***true***

Comment: Is your question about Angular JS (1.x) or Angular (2+)? (Your title and tags disagree ...)

Comment: @meriton  Sorry for that. I am using Angular 6

Comment: This link will be helpful to you [div's content editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378087/how-to-use-ngmodel-on-divs-contenteditable-in-angular2)

Comment: @Suryan thank a lot. I look into it