# unable to get the value of a div in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get the value of a div but I am getting `undefined` value whenever I try to get the value my code is,

```
<div (click)="celebraties()" (ngModel)="1" value="1" class="cus-col" ">
        <div class="cus-text">
          <h4>Celebrities</h4>
        </div>
      </div
```

and my ts code is

```
export class HomePage {
  1 : string;
  id : string;
  celebrity : string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl:ViewController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');


  }

  celebraties(){

    console.log(this[1]);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, property/variable names can't start with number in java/type-script. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables#An_aside_on_variable_naming_rules).

Second, I would not recommend not to use `(ngModel)` and `[value]` together. Instead, use banana-in-the-box `[(ngModel)]`. Read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel).

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that ***NgModel expects the bound element to have a value property, which divs don't have***.

Please go through the link

[How to use [(ngModel)] on div's contenteditable in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378087/how-to-use-ngmodel-on-divs-contenteditable-in-angular2)